# Printing SVG-PictureFiles in C# PrintDocument GDI+

Tags: c#, printing, gdi+, system.drawing, printdocument

I coded a tool which prints small labels. Here´s my problem:

Every printed text on the label looks fine with `e.Graphics.DrawString(...)` -

Pictures printed with `e.Graphics.DrawImage(...)` look bad. Small parts like a Copyright-Sign is not readable.

DPI is set to 300 (maximum of printer).

I got those pictures in Vector/SVG-Format from Corel Draw - if I print the Corel Draw File it looks great!

How can I print SVG-Files or similar with C# (.NET 3.5 or 4.0)?

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used [SVG#](http://sourceforge.net/projects/svgdomcsharp/) before and it worked very well.  The project is old, so it might need minor tweaking before it compiles in your .net 3.5/4.0 projects.

Once you get it compile, you may then try to the following snippet

```cs
//Create a window that matches the desired output bitmap
SvgWindow window = new SvgWindow(width, height);
window.Src = svgSource;

//Create a GDI renderer for SVG, and use white background
GdiRenderer gdirender = new GdiRenderer(window, Color.White);
Bitmap bitmap = gdirender.Render();
```

It should generate a bitmap object that you may use to encode for your printing needs.

Comment: thanks - i installed it. but how to use now? which dll do i have to import to load and print an SVG file in gdi?

Comment: After a few test-prints we decided to use EMF-Format. So we just have to user the `Metafile`-.NET-Class. But your code-sample is definitely helpful for future projects. Thanks! :-)

Comment: Not working. Throwing lots of useless exceptions which are not described or fixed.

Comment: `SvgWindow` requires `System.Windows.Forms` which is nonsense.